Rails 7 Delete links insidea turboframe with dataturbo false are not pointing to delete action
I follow this reference Delete link sends Get request instead of Delete Rails 7
But looks like It is not working for me
I have this link inside a turbo_frame
<%= link_to t("delete"), post_path(post), method: :delete, class: "font-medium text-red-600 underline hover:no-underline hover:text-red-500", data: { confirm: t("are_you_sure") , turbo: false } %>

And the confirm is not appearing and also the request is a GET
I tested adding a byebug on the destroy action and is not triggered when I press the link.
Instead this works
<%= link_to t("delete"), post, method: :delete, class: "font-medium text-red-600 underline hover:no-underline hover:text-red-500", data: { turbo_confirm: t("are_you_sure"), turbo_method: :delete } %>

But I need a full page redirect in order to redirect users to the posts_path
Ideas why the confirm and the disable turbo is pointing to the GET an not to the delete ?
Here is the post_controller destroy method
 def destroy
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, status: :see_other }
    end
  end


seems relevant: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41676

Does this answer your question? Rails 7 - link_to with method :delete still performs GET request, or This? It seems the preferred method these days it to use button_to

BTW turbolinks != turboframe

Nope, all the time Im redirected to the post show with content missing when I use the button with turbo enabled. And when turbo is false, the confirm do not shows ..

just use data: {turbo_frame: "_top"} https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/frames#frame-with-overwritten-navigation-targets

Links by design send GET requests. If you want them to do anything else you need to have a event handler that prevents the default event and creates a virtual form and submits it. That's what the data-turbo-method handler does. If you disable turbo on the link you shouldn't throw a suprised Pickachu face when the link does exactly what it's designed to.

You should alse be aware that "Waaah, my link doesn't delete!" is the perenial unanswerable Rails question and that the questions and answers are usually very low quality and should be taken with bucket loads of salt. The accepted answer to the question you linked doesn't even work as Turbo uses data-turbo-method and not data-method as the old Rails UJS driver did. Refer to the guides instead https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality
